# XMLEncoder аналог для Android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Нуждаюсь в помощи.

Есть готовый апплет содержащий код

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        XMLEncoder enc = new XMLEncoder(bos);
        XmlSerializer o = buildFromObject(entry);
        enc.writeObject(o);
```

Появилась потребность перенести эту часть на Android. Класса XMLEncoder Android SDK не имеет. И нормального порта так же не удалось найти.
Какие еще существуют варианты преобразовать объект в XML аналогичным образом как это делает XMLEncoder? 
Вариант задавать все ветки в ручную не подходит.
Заранее спасибо ща помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошего решения для сериализации XML объектов под Android вроде бы нет. Есть разве что [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) - он не все поддерживает под Android, но попробовать можно.